# How do I decompose the 3-D idenity matrix into lower dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been comfortable writing things like $\mathbb{I}_{x,y}\otimes\mathbb{I}_{z}=\mathbb{I}_{x,y,z}$ but now I realize I have no idea how the actual mechanics of it work. My first, naive attempt was

\begin{eqnarray}
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
\end{array} \right)_{x,y}\otimes(1)_{z}
\end{eqnarray}

But of course this does not work. Is it even correct to use the tensor product?

I find most of my texts (in quantum mechanics) use this kind of notation, but so far I haven't found one that shows what the actual calculation looks like.